# does /github/home persist between github actions?

Tags: github, github-actions

So far, I was under the impression as per the [file system](https://developer.github.com/actions/creating-github-actions/accessing-the-runtime-environment/#filesystem) docs that (only?) `/github/workspace` persists across actions (not workflows):

> The working directory of the Docker container. 
>   GitHub Actions execute in this directory. 
>   The path to this directory is set in the `GITHUB_WORKSPACE` environment variable.

(...)

> An action can modify the contents of this directory, which
>   subsequent actions can access.

But **I now have a [reprex](https://github.com/maxheld83/persistent-home) (live repo with action runs) showing that `/github/home` also appears to persist across actions.**

Of course I understand that none of these persist across workflows, or runs. Just between actions.

The documentation (to me) is a bit unclear about this, and I haven't gotten an answer from support.

Log from first action on `/github/home`:

```
Running 'touch /github/home/foo'...
Successfully ran 'touch /github/home/foo'
```

Log from second action on `/github/home`:

```
Running 'ls /github/home'...
foo
Successfully ran 'ls /github/home'
Running 'rm /github/home/foo'...
Successfully ran 'rm /github/home/foo'
```

That seems to suggest that indeed, `/github/home` also persists, but I'd like to know for sure.

Comment: AFAIK, both GITHUB_HOME & GITHUB_WORKSPACE persists across actions.

Answer (score 4):

My quick answer to your question is: /github/home doesn't persis between jobs/actions.

Following, my tests:

## Write file on a job, try to read on the next

Used [test file](https://github.com/TiagoGouvea/github-actions-test/blob/4eb26cd29db612e94882211c51884f1e175ac98d/.github/workflows/cache.yml).

1) **Writing on `GITHUB_WORKSPACE`**
My path: /home/runner/work/github-actions-test/github-actions-test)
Results: writeable and readble on first job, but, empty on second job
[Action link](https://github.com/TiagoGouvea/github-actions-test/commit/b5c650b1974cdbcdbacb33057da3f2d24126e7ed/checks)

2) **Writing on `/github/home`**
My path: /github/home
Results: `cannot access '/github/home/`
[Action link](https://github.com/TiagoGouvea/github-actions-test/commit/96876dba794a09af146ec7a2f42534aa7d71aecf/checks#step:2:1)

3) **Writing on `/home`**
My path: /home
Results: `touch: cannot touch '/home/myFile.txt': Permission denied`
[Action link](https://github.com/TiagoGouvea/github-actions-test/commit/4eb26cd29db612e94882211c51884f1e175ac98d/checks#step:2:1)

## Conclusion

My conclusion for now (August 23th 2019) is that **cannot persist files**  between jobs on any folder.

Answer (score 0):

GitHub Actions support confirmed that all of `/github` persists throughout a workflow run.

Comment: Can you provide any citation? I am struggling to find any documentation on this.